# Subtraction of variable PHP

Tags: php, html

i cant figure out how can i subtract 2 from a variable ($energia) each time i click on a html link. Problem is that it only subtracts once, so the output will always be 18.

```
<?php 
$energia = 20;


if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $energia != 0)
{
$energia -=2;

}
}
?>


<a href="?action" >subtract</a> <?php echo $energia2; ?>
```

Comment: You seem to set energia at 20 every time, so 20-2 is always 18

Comment: well, you can use ajax if want to use php to do the work or javascript

Comment: Sidenote: You have one `}` too many.

Comment: Sounds like you're not aware of state.. or that PHP runs on a server not the client. Everytime a script starts it has no knowledge of previous executions.. you need to program that functionality.

Comment: yeah. Just use javascript for that.

Comment: Yes 20 is the default energy, but id like to subract 2 each time i click on the "subract" link. So when it is 18 how can i tell to subract 2 from 18 etc? Well id like to do it php :D ik in javascript it is very easy to do.

Comment: Store it ($energia) somewhere that persists, such as $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, datebase, file etc. If you cannot find it, initialize it to 20. If you find it then decrement it and persist it again! Yes, just maintaining a count is  'interesting' in 'client - server' land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this give you the result you want?

```
<?php
//checks if num is set, if not, set it to 20 by default
/*
The following line is the same as
if(isset($_GET["num"]))
{
    $energia = $_GET["num"];
}
else
{
    $energia = 20;
}
*/
//value       condition             if true     else
$energia = isset($_GET["num"]) ? $_GET["num"] : 20;

//if action was clicked and energia is not 0 (not to go in negatives)
//remove && $energia != 0 to allow negative numbers
if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $energia != 0)
{
    //substract 2 from energia
    $energia -=2;
}
?>
```

This line sets action to true AND also stores the value of energia in the substact link string. When clicked, it is retrieved with $_GET["num"]. After the link, the current value (same as in the link) is shown to the user.

```
<a href="?action=true&amp;num=<?php echo $energia; ?>" >subtract</a> <?php echo $energia; ?>
```

Comment: where's $energia2 coming from?

Comment: Please use updated answer, using &amp; is preferred to just & in href

Comment: +1 Sidenote: If OP wants to go below that, -2, -4, -6 etc. can just omit `&& $energia != 0` (*My 2 cents*)

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i want, now i must figure out what you did, thank you very much.

Comment: Is it worthwhile mentioning that, as it is in the URL, anyone can edit it to a different value. Maybe, it would be worthwhile storing a 'server side' copy so that you can check the input is what you sent out?

Comment: Well I am supposing he is not going to put that code in prod - just learning, but that is entirely correct Ryan. If its important to the user, it would be stored in a database or important to the page in the session.

Comment: was not  criticizing! was a genuine question. just being aware of the issues is enuff at this stage. goodness, i put parameters in the URL. if someone tampers with them, well, the program will not bother as they are validated.

Comment: @RyanVincent I didn't take it as criticism. Also, based on your comment in the OP, know that cookies can be edited by the user too.

Comment: **all** and **any** client side input can be edited by the user. Validating it **all** is the way to go. Remember, i mentioned keeping server side copies?

Answer (score 2):

here is a jquery solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCTPk/1/)

html

```
<span class="energia"></span>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="subtract">subtract</a>
```

jquery

```
var energia = 20;
$('.energia').text(energia);
$(document).on('click','.subtract', function(){
       energia -= 2;
       $('.energia').text(energia);
        return false;
});
```